# Overriding a function does not work as expected

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, solidity-0.8.x

I'm not sure I understand how overriding a function works in solidity. I am working on an ERC721 token based on the OpenZeppelin implementation. OpenZeppelin's ERC721.sol contains the following functions:

```
contract ERC721 is Context, ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata {

    function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
        address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
        return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
    }

    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
        address owner = _owners[tokenId];
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: owner query for nonexistent token");
        return owner;
    }
}
```

In my contract, I would like to override `ownerOf`, so I have the following code:

```
contract MyNFT is
    Context,
    AccessControlEnumerable,
    Ownable,
    ERC721Enumerable,
    ERC721Pausable
{
    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (address) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "DramaLlamas: ownership query for nonexistent token");

        address owner = _owners[tokenId];
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            return _creatorAddress;
        } else {
            return owner;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `ownerOf` externally, this works as expected. However, when I call `transferFrom`, the code is using the original version of `ownerOf` NOT the overridden version in `MyNFT`. This is not the behavior I would expect. I want every call for `ownerOf` to use the overridden function.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do without creating overrides of all the functions in OpenZeppelin's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blame is on `_isApprovedOrOwner` it is calling explicitly the implementation on ERC721 due to `ERC721.ownerOf`.

```
function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
    address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
    return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
}
```

If you override `ownerOf` it will still call to the `ERC721` implementation.

Perhaps you want to override `_isApprovedOrOwner` instead.

Comment: Great catch! Unfortunately, the OpenZeppelin ERC721 implementation has several instances where this `ownerOf` call is hardcoded. I ended up forking it and changing it to my requirements.